# Getting javax.net.ssl.SSL.HandshakeException:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException

Tags: automation, junit4, bdd, intuit-partner-platform, karate

I am trying to use the karate tool for rest API testing.

I have set up Karate with below dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The feature is as shown below.

```
Feature: test get

Scenario: get method
Given url 'https://xxxxxx.com'
When method GET
Then status 200
```

When I execute this I am getting

> com.intuit.karate.exception.karateexceprion: java.net.UnknownHostException: xxxxxxx.com

The same script works fine without connecting to VPN.

I do not have class path, karat-config.js in the folder structure. Should that matter?

The site i am trying to test is https and has authentication pop up/splash screen where user is expected to enter the credentials. Once user enters this he gets the homepage.

Should ssl be enabled for this? if so how?

I tried to specify the proxy and port

```
Feature: test get
Background:
    *configure proxy = {url:'proxy:port',username:'user',password:'password') 

Scenario: get method
    Given url 'https://xxxxxx.com'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

Now  *configure proxy = {url:'proxy:port',username:'user',password:'password') and Given url 'https://xxxxxx.com' passed but When method GET failed with error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSL.HandshakeException:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.securoty.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certication path to requested target.
```

Please suggest what needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

> The same script works fine without connecting to VPN.

Clearly the problem is because you don't have a network connection to google. Try `ping`. This is not a Karate issue at all.

My advice is forget google and start trying to connect to the servers you *actually* need to test.

Comment: *configure proxy = {url:'proxy:port',username:'user',password:'password')  in the background. Now the step "When method GET" is failing with error javax.net.ssl.SSL.HandshakeException:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.securoty.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certication path to requested target. This website when tried manually gives authentication pop up where on entering the user name and password it takes the user to homepage. please suggest what needs to be done.

Comment: tried adding the following in background * configure ssl = true and * configure proxy = {url:'proxy:port',username:'user',password:'password'} but got error. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder.setProtocol(Ljava/lang/String:)Lorg/apache/http/ssl/SSLContextBuilder; Kindly suggest what needs to be done

Comment: sounds like you have a conflict with some other dependencies in your maven `pom.xml` which you have to figure out yourself. if you are still stuck - follow the instructions here please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: This worked after adding org.apache.httpcore jar. thanks for all the help